# How to avoid the temporary display of 'alt' when replacing an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a site that dynamically loads content, replacing images based on the results of the content. While the browser loads the images, however, the alt attribute is displayed, often in an unsightly manner. I'd like to keep the alt attribute if possible, but the image should display without flashing the 'alt' attribute while the browser downloads the image. Has anyone run into this problem and found a solution?

I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Maybe consider hiding your image element (display:none; etc) until the image loads successfully.

Comment: I guess that's the what alt should do? :) Display before/if not image is downloaded.

Comment: Are you pre-filling the width and height of the images?  That used to work great in IE to avoid page floating around during download.

Comment: "Has anyone run into this problem". It's not a bug, it's a feature. In other words, this is simply how things work.

Comment: @DA., he never said it was a bug, but that it was a problem. In his case, this behavior, even though by design, causes him problems.

Comment: @Xeon06 and, based on experience, fixing 'problems' that are really changing the default behavior of browsers tends to introduce much bigger problems down the line.

Comment: @DA pretty much all ajax implementations can be said to change the default behavior of the browser; I understand where you're coming from, but there are always situations where the rules need to be bent. That's why I posted my question. Thanks for defending my Q Xeon06!

Comment: @JoBu1324 I wasn't trying to claim the question is bad. I was trying to save you from having to go down that path. Usually, things like this aren't really as big of problems as the project owner thinks and sometimes it helps to step back and rethink how much time and code you want to throw at it. It's certainly a valid question, though!

Comment: @DA Thanks for the clarification! Based on that you're comment was correct. It was already clear in my mind that this was the best option for my app when I wrote the question. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could "preload" your image and only once it's loaded swap the `src`.

```
var tmp = new Image();
tmp.src = "yourimage.png";
tmp.onload = function() {
    $("#actual_image").prop("src", tmp .src);
};
```

Comment: The Alt tag appears while the browser downloads the images. To prevent this you could preload all of the "swap" images by using an Image variable as Xeon06 has suggested. This is used when mouse over effects are desired so that the images can reside in memory.

Comment: Preloading the image seems to work for me, although my implementation is a bit different (I load the images directly on the page in a "key")

Answer (score 3):

You could temporarily supporess the alt-text while the image is loading. Something like this:

```
$(function ()
{
    var ATTR = 'alt';

    $('img').each(function ()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data(ATTR, $this.prop(ATTR)).removeProp(ATTR);
    }).load(function ()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop(ATTR, $this.data(ATTR);
    });
});
```

---

Refactored version:

```
$(function ()
{
    var ATTR = 'alt';

    function disableAlt()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data(ATTR, $this.prop(ATTR)).removeProp(ATTR);
    }

    function enableAlt()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop(ATTR, $this.data(ATTR);
    }

    $('img').each(disableAlt).load(enableAlt);
});
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but I'll mark your answer up just the same since it would work.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the source of the image try this:

```
$('#image-id').fadeOut(250, function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'new-source.jpg');
}).on('load', function () {
    $(this).fadeIn(250);
});
```

This will fade-out the image so it is not visible, then change it's source, and when the image has loaded it will fade back in.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xSkau/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same as `.bind()` in this case.

Comment: +1 If I was going to load my images "nicely", this is solution I'd implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can store alt in data attribute and then add alt attribute to image after the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var alt = $('#myimg').attr('alt');
$('#myimg').attr('alt', '');
$('#myimg').load(function () {
    $(this).attr('alt', alt);
});
```

Comment: Oh, loads of people ninja'd me... Shouldn't answer SO on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to MДΓΓ БДLL's answer above, but more jQueryish:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    $this.data("alt", $this.attr("alt")).removeAttr("alt");
}).load(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr($this.data("alt")); 
});
```

What this does is brutally simple: for each `<img>`, store it's `alt` attribute in jQuery's cache, remove the attribute, then load the image. When that's done, set the `alt` back to what it was, pulling the value from the cache.